# Inline style an SVG imported as a ReactComponent

Tags: css, reactjs, inline-styles

When importing an SVG image as a react component, is it possible to apply inline styles to the `svg` element?

The following does not work, as the style gets applied to the element rather than the svg path:

```
import { ReactComponent as MyIcon } from "./my-icon.svg";

function MyComponent({}) {
  return <MyIcon style={{ fill: "blue" }} />; // Doesnt effect the SVG
}
```

[image]

I know that I can apply a `className`, then style the svg path in CSS, e.g:

```
<MyIcon className='my-icon' />
```

```css
.my-icon {
  path {
    fill: blue;
  }
}
```

[image]

But the color is determined dynamically and is not known by the CSS (actually I'm using SCSS, but the same principle applies).

I understand that perhaps using a library like Emotion or Styled Components would solve this problem, but I'm wondering if it can be done inline without any additional packages.